# The most elementary matrices required to invert a $2 \times 2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> What is  largest amount of elementary matrices required to invert a $2 \times 2$ matrix?

I got $4$ as my answer. Is that correct? Can you pleasehelp me with this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, 4 is correct if you allow two types of elementary matrices: matrices with 1's on the diagonal and at most 1 nonzero entry off the diagonal, and diagonal matrices with at most one diagonal entry different from 1.

Since the inverse of a product of invertible elementary matrices is a product of the same number of elementary matrices (because the inverse of each invertible elementary matrix is an elementary matrix) it suffices to show that each invertible 2x2 matrix is the product of at most 4 elementary matrices.

If $a \ne 0$, then a $2\times 2$ matrix with $a$ in the upper corner can be written as a product of 4 elementary matrices:

$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ \frac{c}{a} & 1 \end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & d-\frac{bc}{a} \end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \frac{b}{a} \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right) =
\left( \begin{array}{cc} a & b \\ c & d \end{array}\right)
$$

Notice that when $a=1$, three elementary matrices suffice.

If $a=0$  but $c\ne 0$, then 
$$
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \frac{1}{c} \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)=
\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & * \\ c & d\end{array}\right)
$$
Since $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & * \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ can be written as a product of 3 elementary matrices,  $\left( \begin{array}{cc} 0 & b \\ c & d\end{array}\right)$ can again be written as the product of 4.

If $a$ and $c$ and are both zero, the matrix is singular so we can't invert it.