# Writing a given matrix as a product of fewest elementary matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

> Write the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$ as a product of elementary matrices, using as few as you can, and prove that your expression is as short as possible.

---

I wrote the matrix as a product of elementary matrices

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\\ 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 \\\ 0 &1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$$

However, I am facing problem to prove that this expression is the shortest one .

Can I say we will require at least 3 row reduction to convert $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$
into a identity matrix. Is this a valid proof.

Comment: How do you define "elementary matrices"?

Comment: An elementary matrix is a matrix which differs from the identity matrix by one single elementary row operation.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437900/writing-a-matrix-as-a-product-of-elementary-matrices) for more context.

Comment: ..and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1986289) (not an answer, though).

Comment: But there is no proof of being shortest product

Comment: Just compute the product of two elementary matrices and compare with your matrix. This gives equations which you can solve. For example $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \cr 3 & 4 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 3 & -2 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \cr 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$ But of course with elementary matrices (are those elementary or not)?